# Templating issues outputting bigquery data using GAE render or Jinja2 template

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I have completed most of the [Codelab: Creating a BigQuery Dashboard](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/articles/dashboard). However, I am running into templating issues that I can't seem to resolve.

**Python:**

```
import jinja2
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.template import render 

JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(
loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'],
autoescape=True)

def query(self):
    ....
    response = service.jobs().query(projectId=projectId, body=query).execute()
    return response

def _bq2geo(self, bqdata):
    logging.info(bqdata)
    table = Table()

    column1 = bqdata['schema']['fields'][0]['name']
    column2 = bqdata['schema']['fields'][1]['name']

    table.add_column(column1, str, column1)
    table.add_column(column2, int, column2)

    for row in bqdata['rows']:
        table.append([str(row['f'][0]['v']), int(row['f'][1]['v'])])
    return encode(table)

def get(self):
    data = self.query()
    mydata = self._bq2geo(data)

    template = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'index.html')
    self.response.out.write(render(template, json.dumps(mydata)))
```

The last two lines result in:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token %

Which I'm sure is related to this in my JavaScript:

[image: JavaScript not accepting autoescape]

When I use [jinja2](/questions/tagged/jinja2) instead, I end up with a different error:

```
 template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('index.html')
 self.response.out.write(template.render(json.dumps(mydata)))
```

> ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

I'm following the [Generating Dynamic Content from Templates](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/getting-started/generating-dynamic-content-templates) so I don't understand why I need to pass in 2 elements.

---

**HTML:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/script.js"></script>

<body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
</body>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages' : ['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

mydata = {% autoescape off %}{{ pydata }}{% endautoescape %}

function drawChart(){
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(mydata);

var options = {
    hAxis: {
        showTextEvery: 1
    }
};

var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

- Desired outcome: View Google chart in browser
- Current outcome: Nothing shows on the screen, different error messages in developer console (depending on the template method)

*How can I resolve this issue (preferably using Jinja2) to output the chart?*

Comment: Isn't it `{% autoescape false %}`?  Or, alternatively, `{{ pydata|safe }}`.

Comment: I tried both `false` and `|safe` and I still get an error message: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` (using the first templating method)

Comment: View the source code in your browser to see what it is being fed, or put it in quotes to make it a string: `mydata = "{{ pydata|safe }}";`  You are feeding that to a javascript variable, so it has to be able to parse it as proper code.  Post the source code here if you wish, so we can diagnose. (I you put it in quotes, and there are quotes in `pydata`, then you will get another syntax error.  View the source code to see what you have.)